# Is there an order to apply time shifting and frequency shifting to signals in DTFT?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform

For instance in one question applying frequency shifting first and then applying time shifting yields a different answer wrt applying time shifting first. Please elaborate i am clueless.

if i use frequency shift first then i get ans a which wrong but if i do time shifting first and then time shifting i get d,which is the correct option
[image]

Comment: Hint: if two operations characterise LTI systems, then they can be applied in any order. Thus, determine whether *time-shift* and *freq-shift* operations correspond to LTI systems or not.

Comment: @Fat32 I have updated the question please check and help

Comment: I find it helpful with Fourier transform properties questions to try it out on a sine wave, because you can do it with just trig, on paper, without dealing with the Fourier transform.  So -- if you time shift a sine wave and then frequency shift, does it give you the same answer as if you frequency shift and then time shift?  If no (for a general sine wave), then it isn't going to happen with the Fourier transform, either.  If yes, then it probably will.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Multiplication with a complex exponential is NOT an LTI operation.
2. Multiplication in the time domain corresponds to convolution with the frequency domain.
3. Calculate the individual FTs for each of the signals that are being multiplied and then convolve the results